# Can't install pyqt5-tools

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to install pyqt5-tools, but I get this error:

```
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ep3u6c42\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
        File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ep3u6c42\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ep3u6c42\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 585, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1b7x6air\pyqt5_fd0c08501ddd4417a50eaaa8c052ebbf\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ep3u6c42\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ep3u6c42\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 236, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ep3u6c42\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 69, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Someone know how to resolve this? I have already installed pyqt5, and I have tried basically everything, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be using version 3.10 of the Python language. Pyqt5-tools works best in python 3.9. You can review "https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/" here.